# How to configure <context-param> programmatically without web.xml

Tags: servlets, context-param

Is there any other way to configure a context parameter excluding the one which uses `web.xml` as in the below example?

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: When is 'programmatically setting' required?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since Servlet 3.0, you can programmatically set them via [`ServletContext#setInitParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setInitParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Just put below [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) anywhere in your web project. The [`@WebListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation will make the container to automatically pickup and run it during webapp startup.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext(); 
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews", "10");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

}
```

Comment: @BalusC how to set context-param programmatically for servlet 2.5?

Comment: Upgrade to Servlet 3.0 or newer. It was released a decade ago already.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using embedded Tomcat, it is like this:

```
Context.getServletContext()
    .getServletRegistrations()
    .get("webdavservlet")
    .setInitParameter("listings", "true");
```

Comment: how to set context-param programmatically for servlet 2.5?